# Echarts Treemap data structure is expecting 'name' and 'value' properties. Is there a way to provide data fields to be used as 'name and 'value'?

Tags: treemap, echarts

In Echarts, Treemap data structure is expecting 'name' and 'value' properties. Is there a way to provide data fields to be used as 'name and 'value' ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the formatter property inside label.

```
tooltip: {
    show: true,
    formatter: '{a} <br> Category : {b} <br> Value : {c}'
  },
```

String template

Model variation includes:

1. `{a}` : series name.
2. `{b}` : the name of a data item.
3. `{c}` : the value of a
4. data item. `{@xxx}`: the value of a dimension named 'xxx', for
   example, `{@product}` refers the value of 'product' dimension.
5. `{@[n]}`: the value of a dimension at the index of n, for example, `{@[3]}` refers the value at dimensions[3].

example:

`formatter: '{b}: {@score}'`